# Redshift Dependence in the Spatial Orientation of SDSS Galaxies having Redshift 0.19 to 0.20

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

Does [redshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) depend on the
spatial orientation of [SDSS galaxies](http://www.sdss.org/) with redshift in the range 0.19 to 0.20 ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Is there a *real* correlation between redshift and orientation? Is there some bias introduced in the SDSS pipeline? Clearly there must be background to this question, given those specific numbers.

Comment: I too don't think there is correlation between redshift and orientation. Would you please clear what might be the correlation between red filter band and redshift in the study of spatial orientation of Galaxies?